# Send a Javascript array in a mail

Tags: javascript, php

I have an HTML form to retrieve some options from checkboxes:

```
     <form action="" method="post" id="menuform" name="menuform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select a Menu</legend>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="selectedmenu" checked value="menu01" ape-qty='8' ent-qty='1' pes-qty='1' sor-qty='1' car-qty='1' pos-qty='1' data-price='95' />
                <span>First Item</span>
            </label>
            ...(more)...
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend id='aperitivosPrompt'>Elegir Aperitivos</legend>
            <label>
                <input type='checkbox' name='aperitivos' value="1" />
                <span>Item 1</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type='checkbox' name='aperitivos' value="2" />
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type='checkbox' name='aperitivos' value="3" />
                <span>Item 3</span>
            </label>
            ...(more)...
        </fieldset>            
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </fieldset>
     </form>
```

Then I send this variables to a JavaScript file and I save all checkboxes options in multiple arrays

```
var menuform = document.getElementById('menuform'),
    radios = document.getElementsByName('selectedmenu'),
    aperitivos = document.getElementsByName('aperitivos'),
    aperitivosPrompt = document.getElementById('aperitivosPrompt'),
    totalPrice = document.getElementById('totalPrice'),
    result = document.getElementById('result'),
    aperitivosAllowed = 0,
    currentSelectionAperitivos = [],
    currency = '€';

function handleAperitivos(e) {
    var count = getSelectedCountApe();
    if (count > aperitivosAllowed) {
        resetSelectApe();
    } else {
        currentSelectionAperitivos = getSelectedValuesApe();
    }
}
...(more)...
function getSelectedCountApe() {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < aperitivos.length; i++) {
        if (aperitivos[i].checked) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
...(more)...
```

So, how can I send these arrays named `currentSelectionAperitivos = []` in an email? I want that after user selects all his options, I receive an email in my inbox with his selected options.

I think that I must connect this form and `JS` file with a `PHP` function and send emails from there. Anyway, how can I do this?

-EDITED-

I tried a solution with JSON:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aperitivos.length; i++) {
    var item = {
        "valor": i,
        "etiqueta": aperitivos[i].value
    };
    currentSelectionAperitivos.push(item);
}
currentJSON = JSON.stringify({currentSelectionAperitivos:currentSelectionAperitivos});
console.log(currentJSON);
```

So now I get in browser console all "values" from fields `<input>` of the HTML form. But not only CHECKED values and anyway, what I need now is to get this JSON.stringify and send it by mail with PHP.

Comment: Where is the php that is processing the form?

Comment: research on how to send form data via email with PHP

Comment: Checkout phpmailer. One of the simplest php email plugin out there https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I think you will have a lot of trouble if you want to send javascript right out of user-recieved mail. I would made a special page and send link to this page (maybe with a sort of token) in e-mail in that case.

Comment: @jeroen there is no php file yet because I'm trying to figure out how to develop that part

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaH, I will try that solution!

Answer (score 0):

Write a PHP script to send the email, change the form action to post on this script.

Attention: this is untested.

Change your form to:

```
<form action="mail.php"...>
</form>
```

Create mail.php like

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  var_dump($_POST);
  $result = ob_get_clean();
  mail ( 'your@email.com' , 'subject' , $result);
?>
```

Otherwise you could use JSON.stringify and an API to send the E-Mail with JS.

Comment: Not working for me that simple solution. Nothing happens when I click send button.

Comment: Seems var_export didn't return a string as I thaught it would. The edited example above does work. If you want to get the state of multiple checkboxes you should use `name='aperitivos[]'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for my needs. I get all 'checked' values and I create an email with theme.

So, HTML form:

```
<html>   
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/assets/application-09059f9f54cc3c3bff98487cf866644b.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="configurador.php" method="post" id="menuform" name="menuform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend id='itemPrompt'>Choose Item</legend>
            <label>
                <input type='checkbox' name='item' value="Value#01" />
                <span>Value#01</span>
            </label>
            (...more...)
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

So there I have all my 'checkboxes' with values and names. I made some JavaScript functions but most important one is this one where I retrieve all values and send theme in an email:

```
function sendMail() {
    var mailbody = "My Configurator: \n\n"
                    + $('input[name="item"]')
                    .map(function(id, box){ return (box.checked ? "[x]" : "[_]") + " " + box.value;})
                    .get()
                    .join("\n");
    var link = "mailto:mail@mail.com"
                + "?cc="
                + "&subject=" + escape("Configurator - Subject")
                + "&body=" + escape(mailbody);
    window.location.href = link;
}

$(function(){
    $( "#menuform" ).sisyphus();
});
```

And it's OK with just this. But I'm getting all checkboxes, even not checked ones, in that email. And could be perfect if I don't have to open a client mail, just send that mail from my server automatically.

**Any solution for this variation?**